# pdf file as empty from API response : Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am calling one rest API which is returning pdf file. However, it is showing as blank when i open it.
Through console it seems data is getting corrupted.

```
let url ="API-URL";
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': url ,
    'id': '50d55684-9c61-4843-b023-1a9270ff5768',
    'format': 'pdf',
    'encoding': 'binary',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': auth,
    },
    
    
  };
  process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
  // Return new promise 
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
      request.get(options, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
              reject(err);
          } 
          else {
            console.log(typeof response.body);
            fs.writeFile("./test.pdf", response.body, 'binary', (err) => {
              if(err) {
                  return console.log(err);
              }
              console.log("The file was saved!");
          }); 
            resolve(response.body);
            
          }
      })
  })
```

I followed one of solution provided to set encoding as binary or null. But both didnt work for me.

The pdf data looks like below

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Subtype/Form/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Matrix[1 0 0 1 0 0]/FormType 1/Resources<</ColorSpace<</CSpg/DeviceGray/PCSp 5 0 R/CSp/DeviceRGB>>/ExtGState<</GSa 6 0 R/GState99 7 0 R/GState136 8 0 R/GState137 9 0 R/GState138 10 0 R>>/Pattern<<>>/Font<<>>/XObject<</Im49 11 0 R/Im29 12 0 R/Im126 13 0 R/Im41 14 0 R/Im85 15 0 R/Im102 16 0 R/Im21 17 0 R/Im65 18 0 R/Im45 19 0 R/Im89 20 0 R/Im106 21 0 R/Im25 22 0 R/Im69 23 0 R/Im130 24 0 R/Im81 25 0 R/Im134 26 0 R/Im61 27 0 R/Im110 28 0 R/Im17 29 0 R/Im53 30 0 R/Im97 31 0 R/Im33 32 0 R/Im77 33 0 R/Im114 34 0 R/Im13 35 0 R/Im57 36 0 R/Im37 37 0 R/Im118 38 0 R/Im9 39 0 R/Im93 40 0 R/Im122 41 0 R/Im73 42 0 R>>>>/Length 450365/BBox[0 0 792 612]>>stream
x��͎,=���O�k�r��Nr]0
�����p��@���R/���f��sY���e|�U��<t�h��Ϳ��y����������}������������ߎ�����ox�÷�}������?|��l������~3�6����?^����������/�����|��_�0���o5ٿ?��\���5���������K�_����_�_�����?����Ֆ�����?:����=���鯼��^�~����MX�K_��nº  �&���nº �%�Ŷ�׼��v��qoǽ�v���&w��RƗ~���nº  �&���n�z    �z���5���v��qoǽ�v�������MX�K_��nº    �&���nº �%�Ŷ�׼��v��qoǽ�v��qo��o��nr7a�.e|�w�  �&���nº �&�� �ێ_�n��qoǽ�v��qoǽ/���݄������&���nº    �&���^��^l;~ͻyoǽ�v��qoǽ�v��qoǽ�v��qoǽ�v��qo�m�e    �KSƗ~���nº  �&���n�z    �z���5���v��qoǽ�v��qoǽ�v�ݦ[�N{x�׿?�ߴ�6�{�r:՟4��7��>��o�<����~������n�[?��rT�x=��������_g|E��6����~�_�?~|��h���~���W~\������6�_�d��c��ӿu��x���ٮ �����o����?w&�_6����]}����;������8o���?�����?�;>�����^�>��x�����~����}���������_L�g�x��_���r��������#���������O����[�\P��'����|�|�=����������_�k0��'x��`��G,�����u�}ԣ.�o��ſ�
Nl�=��۷�Ɍ����+D�����KJ6���o?�6��s
'�$��/'��I�����Ӈ�Ye��J�YrVY�c���ח�nj�u��ڎ���j��*y-_/�Z:>�{�J��ty.]y߷\�1����zɩ��Џ7��'���WN_���X�K�Ŷq�X:|��q,�6v��o>g[:�����T�KI�v-����k�s�ƾo��S���J���|��Ԝ|��W�w��7��}N���w�m������<�'n�_ƣ���{�>w���-����r�O��K꽼������n����=��;�3㏿.C1� _����{�w��M_�����������{yo�w߯7}���}�~�ɽ�������z��}����כ���{yo�����c�_:$�KO�������;݋�^�>~*�������1�׿��E�����4��B��<���y�+G�����a>���L�����7?�Ư!0���w������W��7_�|���ٽ�f�7���}voy3��I����%Ʉ�Vb�"$����/v��w��ދ|3ŗ������Oe���E�L�����7S��ޛʾ��W�9/0��?��"�L�zo*�Tv_�_�0��_��ދ|3ŗ�z_�A���z�)��ѿ��w��� �{3țA~��K���W>��"���o��>�7���� oy�ݛA~�E��� o��g�^�A� �7���bw��}^���-��3�_��~S�/Oe���E�L�����7S��ޛʾ��W�9/0��?��"�L�zo*�Tv_�_�0��_��ދ|3ŗ�z_�A���z�)��ѿ��w��� �{3țA~�NP���W>��"���o��>�7���� oy�ݛA~�E��� o��g�^�A�  �7���bw��}^���-��3�_��~S�/Oe���E�L�����7S��ޛʾ��W�9/0��?��"�L�zo*�Tv_�_�0��_��ދ|3ŗ�z_�A���z�)��ѿ��w��� �{3țA~�NP���W>��"���o��>�7���� oy�ݛA~�E��� o��g�^�A��f��ٽ�� oy3������-�� oy3��<��"��f�7����� oy3țA�g�f�_n�oy3țA��ٽ�f�w��L�'����;%��^�)�DՓ��~�Tv_�_�0��_��ދ|3��꽩�KP�}�~���S|��z/������/Ae���E�L�����7S|�����������{�o�zG��>�7���@�2�7?��G�^���-0�g�f�7���� �{3�/��7���� _��ދ|3�;A�&��R�X~˻��n��?�v�ne����?��{ߝ���z/��_"^즲_?��W�9/0��?��"�L�zo*�Tv_�_�0��_��ދ|3��꽩�KP�}�~���S|��z/��_��}1������G�^䛿�т_�A�"b��z��v�E��/���}�����'A��_�ދ|�ÿ5?�Wߏ����������x�~v���'��g���V��'~{o��Z�Z.�����f�c��ogZ���������ʱ�#��1���������/4���~+���u��~��,]���>�.�'
-���EX���d?8�8w�u����=}��|��}?�ftfh\��p>F=v����-���EC��4Tް�<7Cۜ���?rO7;�c���W+��8�-���e���9�<�ް�h��=����S�1��$[�k��?�t�c�k�mal���K���>�����������1���1�r��o2�8��+=]���a�yĚ+���>�Q���>��~�51��[`�O�0t�`hL0�X��6�/��q�c�t�ن64&��\h#o����c���c}]5���L�e���c���Y/Oz96�q{��5�zě�����J�o~X�m��zq^/��=�JO�6t����t�W,�ؿ�}�u|��c  �`/��,����2_��Msu����O������6�({�'�B�x���
��u��8�[�p:J�#ah�{g�n��1��uJ��v�����Ntr��f·��>_عEI�]��T����X_�C�O������C0�����
```

Can someone help me what is the mistake i am doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample solution using Node.js' [fs promises](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) and [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

```
const fs = require('fs').promises,
      request = require('request-promise');

let fileName = './test.pdf',
    options = {
      'method': 'GET',
      'url': ...,
      'encoding': null, // response should be buffer
      ...
    };

request(options)
  .then(response => fs.writeFile(filename, response))
  .then(() => console.log("The file was saved!"))
  .catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: "your Url"
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
  responseEncoding: "binary",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
  }
};

fs.writeFileSync("D://*******//test.pdf", response.data);
fs.close();
```

This worked for me.